# javascript doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript

I made a tutorial on dash.generalassemb.ly and there my code works but if I put in a notepad++ and run in chrome it doesn't work the javascript code.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Londrina+Shadow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>

body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  background: #232323;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Londrina Shadow', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0px 0 70px 0;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background: black;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  transition: height .5s;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s;
  -moz-transition: height .5s;
}

small {
  opacity: 0;
}
.show-description p {
  height: 150px;
}

.show-description small {
  opacity: 1;
}

.first{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/firstcourse.jpg");
}
.second{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/secondcourse.jpg");
}
.dessert{
  background-image: url("http://dash.ga.co/assets/dessertcourse.jpg");
}
.price {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
  }
  div {
    margin: 20px 12px 0 12px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  small {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>esha's restaurant</h1>
  <h2>a New York City eatery</h2>
  <div class="first">
    <p>welsh onion soko <span class="price">$14</span><br />
      <small>Mustard sierra leone bologi kale chard beet greens black-eyed pea sorrel amaranth garlic tigernut spring onion summer purslane asparagus lentil.</small>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <p>pastrami boudin tongue <span class="price">$22</span><br />
      <small>Tri-tip capicola kielbasa salami brisket chicken rump strip steak drumstick. Meatloaf chuck boudin ribeye pork jowl. Andouille bacon jowl meatloaf pork loin prosciutto bresaola.</small>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="dessert">
    <p>fruitcake marzipan pudding dragee <span class="price">$8</span><br />
      <small>Lollipop tart cotton candy jelly-o carrot cake apple pie cupcake. Jelly-o bear claw ice cream candy canes.</small>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

The idea is that if I click inside of one menu it should show me the description for that food.What's wrong? Any help?

Comment: Does `/assets/jquery.js` exist?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: If so put script tag bottom to the body tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery wasn't loaded add this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

(I verified it worked in jsbin)

btw, if javascript didn't work in chrome the entire world would probably go into a standstill so I doubt that.